# Is the guess $\mathrm{moa}(31)=11774$ in the moa function the true value?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

It is conjectured that the map $\mathrm{gnu}: \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ with
$\mathrm{gnu}(n)=\text{the number of groups of order }n$ is surjective.

The $\mathrm{moa}$-function is defined by $\mathrm{moa}(n)=\mathrm{min}${$m \in \mathbb N\ |\ \mathrm{gnu}(m)=n$}. In a table, I came across the guess $\mathrm{moa}(31)=11774$. I am astonished that the $\mathrm{moa}$-value for such a small value $n$ should be not known (maybe it is known now).

I know that $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ is not known for some values, for example $n=2048$, but I thought that the determination of $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ would be easy, if $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ is small, lets say $\mathrm{gnu}(n)\le 100$. The guess is the smallest cubefree number $n$ with $\mathrm{gnu}(n)=31$. There is no $n \leq 2047$ with $\mathrm{gnu}(n)=31$.

- Is it true that $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ can be difficult to determine, even if it is small ?
- Is $\mathrm{moa}(31)=11774$ ?

Comment: The number $11774$ is not so small, I think. There are $31$ groups of order $11774$, and no smaller number than $11774$ with $31$ different groups of that order. That sounds really difficult. Try to find $31$ in this [sequence](http://oeis.org/A000001).

Comment: So, the answer to my first question is : yes ?

Comment: I mean : Is it really difficult to decide whether there are at least $31$ groups of any given order.

Comment: Yes,  I think it is in general very difficult to say this for groups of any given order. You can take $7$ instead of $31$, that is even smaller. But still it is no so obvious to me.

Answer (score 3):

moa(7)=375 by

https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf

moa(31) is the smallest open one there.

To me, checking whether moa(31)=11774 looks difficult, but maybe not impossible.

For every $n$ and every divisor of $d$ of $n$, $gnu(d)\leq gnu(n)$. In particular, our moa must be 5th power-free.
Similarly,  if $n=d_1\cdot d_2$ where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are coprime then, by considering direct products, we have $gnu(n)\geq gnu(d_1)\times gnu(d_2)$.

If $n$ is cubefree then gnu(n) can be computed directly, and similarly, most values of the form $p^aq$ are in the SmallGroups library.

Running a preliminary computation using the above, this leaves a few hundreds values of $n$ up to 11774 to deal with.
Most of them are of the shape $p^3qr$. Probably a somewhat more detailed analysis of this case would be required. (It would not be necessary to computer the exact value of gnu, but simply try to exclude 31 as a possibility, using lower or upper bounds.)

Comment: I am sure that it would be possible to give a complete analysis of group of order $p^3qr$, but as far as I know nobody has done it. It might be a suitable project for a Masters Thesis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[This](https://groups.quendi.de/?total_min=31&total_max=31) query on [Max Horn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12415/max-horn)'s website (select the number of total classes is between $31$ and $31$ option) gives $11774$ as the smallest number with $31$ groups of that order up to isomorphism.

Note that there are some smaller numbers in that database with an unknown total number of groups. But these are numbers such as $2048, 3072, 4096, \dots$ which have a high number of powers of two, (or in the case of $8748$, powers of three). Using the fact that $\mathrm{gnu}$ is supermultiplicative, i.e.

$$\mathrm{gnu}(ab) \geq \mathrm{gnu}(a) \cdot \mathrm{gnu}(b) \quad \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$$

and checking the number of groups of the orders of the large prime powers, we conclude that all those orders must certainly have more than $31$ groups up to isomorphism.

(Also, [A046057](https://oeis.org/A046057) in the OEIS gives $\mathrm{moa}(31) = 11774$. I don't use the OEIS often, but I am fairly certain that they only add a term to a sequence when they are confident it is correct.)