# Does there exist a $n \in \mathbb{N},\; n>1$ such that the number of groups of order $n$ equals $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Does there exist a $n \in \mathbb{N},\; n>1$ such that the number of groups of order $n$ equals $n$?

Me and my friends were just curious and checked the first 1000 numbers (using the internet).

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A000001

Comment: I check up to order $2047$ and the answer is no. A somewhat close hit above $1000$ is $f(1056)=1028$.

Comment: @Zahlenteufel I've edited in your comment, as the question currently has 3 close votes and this is your motivation/context.

Comment: This is open, and has been discussed many times before here, see for example [Is the guess $moa(31)=11774$ in the moa function the true value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580156/is-the-guess-moa31-11774-in-the-moa-function-the-true-value)

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close. This is a legitimate question (and there isn't much the OP could have tried on their own).

Comment: In a paper about gnus, moas and other exotica , the author mentioned the conjecture that there is probably no such $n$ , but the question is , as mentioned , open. The answer is "no" for squarefree numbers , cubefree numbers upto $50\ 000$ , prime powers with exponent not exceeding $4$ and numbers with at most $3$ prime factors (multiplicity considered). This list is not complete, but shows some classes which can be ruled out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We do not know.

Let $a(n)$ be number of groups of order $n$. There is a [conjecture from Conway, Dietrich and O'Brien](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02985731) (see also O'Brien's website [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf)) that the sequence $$n, a(n), a(a(n)), a(a(a(n))), \dots$$
eventually consists of an infinite sequence of $1$.

The number $n$ you are looking for would be a counterexample to this conjecture, which is currently open (and fully checked up to $2047$).

Comment: To be clear:  unless I am not understanding, it's perfectly possible that an elementary argument would show that there was no $n$ of the desired form.  I agree that your argument suggests that we will fail to find an example, but a negative solution should still be possible, yes?

Comment: Sure, the non-existence of a fixed point $n$ would not imply that the conjecture is true (you could have cycles or you could have unbounded growth)

Comment: I think this is one of the weirdest conjectures I have ever seen.